# Fish shell shows dark-grey "âŽ" characters in prompt

Tags: prompt, character-encoding, fish

I'm pretty certain this is some foible of my SSH client (RoyalTS for Windows) but, having just installed and changed to fish shell, my prompt is preceded by two dark-grey `âŽ` characters.

It doesn't seem to do it in PuTTY, just in this particular client, which uses a Rebex plugin.

The fish FAQ talks about random characters and mentions a `fish_title` function, which it tells you how to empty, but this does not seem to have made a difference.

I'm sure they are just some sort of mis-encoded control characters, but I'm just trying to work out what these two characters are, what they are for and how I might get rid of them.

## Edit

As requested, the output of `fish_prompt` hasn't changed since install, and is:

```
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'
    # Just calculate this once, to save a few cycles when displaying the prompt
    if not set -q __fish_prompt_hostname
            set -g __fish_prompt_hostname (hostname|cut -d . -f 1)
    end

    set -l color_cwd
    set -l suffix
    switch $USER
    case root toor
            if set -q fish_color_cwd_root
                    set color_cwd $fish_color_cwd_root
            else
                    set color_cwd $fish_color_cwd
            end
            set suffix '#'
    case '*'
            set color_cwd $fish_color_cwd
            set suffix '>'
    end

    echo -n -s "$USER" @ "$__fish_prompt_hostname" ' ' (set_color $color_cwd) (prompt_pwd) (set_color normal) "$suffix "
end
```

...and `fish_prompt | xxd`:

```
0000000: 726f 6f74 4063 616e 6463 2d77 6230 3170  root@candc-wb01p
0000010: 2d6c 201b 5b33 316d 2f1b 5b33 306d 1b28  -l .[31m/.[30m.(
0000020: 421b 5b6d 2320                           B.[m#
```

...and `functions -an`:

```
# functions -an
., N_, _, __fish_append, __fish_bind_test1, __fish_bind_test2, 
__fish_command_not_found_setup, __fish_commandline_test, 
__fish_complete_abook_formats, __fish_complete_ant_targets, 
__fish_complete_atool, __fish_complete_atool_archive_contents, 
__fish_complete_aura, __fish_complete_bittorrent, 
__fish_complete_cabal, __fish_complete_cd, __fish_complete_command, 
__fish_complete_convert_options, __fish_complete_diff, 
__fish_complete_directories, __fish_complete_file_url, 
__fish_complete_ftp, __fish_complete_grep, __fish_complete_groups, 
__fish_complete_list, __fish_complete_lpr, __fish_complete_lpr_option, 
__fish_complete_ls, __fish_complete_lsusb, __fish_complete_man, 
__fish_complete_mime, __fish_complete_pacman, __fish_complete_path, 
__fish_complete_pgrep, __fish_complete_pids, __fish_complete_ppp_peer, 
__fish_complete_proc, __fish_complete_python, 
__fish_complete_service_actions, __fish_complete_setxkbmap, 
__fish_complete_ssh, __fish_complete_subcommand, 
__fish_complete_subcommand_root, __fish_complete_suffix, 
__fish_complete_svn, __fish_complete_svn_diff, __fish_complete_tar, 
__fish_complete_tex, __fish_complete_unrar, __fish_complete_users, 
__fish_complete_vi, __fish_complete_wvdial_peers, __fish_complete_xsum, 
__fish_config_interactive, __fish_contains_opt, __fish_crux_packages, 
__fish_cursor_konsole, __fish_cursor_xterm, 
__fish_default_command_not_found_handler, __fish_describe_command, 
__fish_filter_ant_targets, __fish_filter_mime, __fish_git_prompt, 
__fish_gnu_complete, __fish_hg_prompt, __fish_is_first_token, 
__fish_is_token_n, __fish_list_current_token, 
__fish_make_completion_signals, __fish_man_page, __fish_move_last, 
__fish_no_arguments, __fish_not_contain_opt, 
__fish_number_of_cmd_args_wo_opts, __fish_paginate, __fish_ports_dirs, 
__fish_print_abook_emails, __fish_print_addresses, 
__fish_print_arch_daemons, __fish_print_cmd_args, 
__fish_print_cmd_args_without_options, __fish_print_commands, 
__fish_print_debian_services, __fish_print_encodings, 
__fish_print_filesystems, __fish_print_function_prototypes, 
__fish_print_help, __fish_print_hostnames, __fish_print_interfaces, 
__fish_print_lpr_options, __fish_print_lpr_printers, 
__fish_print_lsblk_columns, __fish_print_make_targets, 
__fish_print_mounted, __fish_print_packages, 
__fish_print_service_names, __fish_print_svn_rev, __fish_print_users, 
__fish_print_xdg_mimeapps, __fish_print_xdg_mimetypes, 
__fish_print_xrandr_modes, __fish_print_xrandr_outputs, 
__fish_print_xwindows, __fish_prt_no_subcommand, __fish_prt_packages, 
__fish_prt_ports, __fish_prt_use_package, __fish_prt_use_port, 
__fish_pwd, __fish_reconstruct_path, __fish_reload_key_bindings, 
__fish_repaint, __fish_repaint_root, __fish_restore_status, 
__fish_seen_subcommand_from, __fish_systemctl_automounts, 
__fish_systemctl_devices, __fish_systemctl_mounts, 
__fish_systemctl_scopes, __fish_systemctl_service_paths, 
__fish_systemctl_services, __fish_systemctl_slices, 
__fish_systemctl_snapshots, __fish_systemctl_sockets, 
__fish_systemctl_swaps, __fish_systemctl_targets, 
__fish_systemctl_timers, __fish_test_arg, __fish_urlencode, 
__fish_use_subcommand, __fish_winch_handler, __terlar_git_prompt, abbr, 
alias, cd, contains_seq, cp, delete-or-exit, dirh, dirs, 
down-or-search, eval, export, fish_config, fish_default_key_bindings, 
fish_indent, fish_mode_prompt, fish_prompt, fish_sigtrap_handler, 
fish_update_completions, fish_vi_cursor, fish_vi_key_bindings, 
fish_vi_mode, funced, funcsave, grep, help, history, hostname, isatty, 
la, ll, ls, man, math, mcd, mimedb, mv, nextd, nextd-or-forward-word, 
open, popd, prevd, prevd-or-backward-word, prompt_pwd, psub, pushd, rm, 
seq, setenv, sgrep, trap, type, umask, up-or-search, vared,
```

Comment: Anything in your `.profile` (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.login`, etc.) which sets the prompt and has embedded control characters?

Comment: I can't *see* anything in the places you've mentioned, nor in `~/.config/fish/*` -- would fish even use the bash-based ones?

Comment: Ah my bad, didn't read properly, thought fish was your ssh client.  So I'm guessing somewhere in the fish shell config it's setting the prompt or similar to have some control characters which PuTTY happily interprets but RoyalTS doesn't.  Maybe check the term settings in RoyalTS, or dig further into fish (I have no experience of it)

Comment: Looks like a locale problem between your ssh client and the shell. Check your shell's $LANG and $LC* variables, and the client's settings.

Comment: What's the output of: `functions fish_prompt`     ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - added

Comment: @glennjackman - seemingly confirmed.  Found the client setting to set encoding to UTF-8 (`echo $LANG` returned `en_US,UTF-8`).  However, so I might better understand, do you have any idea what those characters were *supposed* to represent?

Comment: I don't have fish available; can you run fish_prompt by hand and investigate the leading characters? Something like: `fish_prompt | xxd`

Comment: it's probably a single unicode character being rendered as two separate characters.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - added output of `xxd`

Comment: I think we miscommunicated; I was trying to get the output of running the fish_prompt function to pipe into xxd -- appears you ran xxd on the the "functions" command?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - my bad, updated

Comment: Interesting -- the "âŽ" characters show up to the *left* of the "root@" part of the prompt?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - Above the prompt and/or below the output of any command...

Comment: I wonder if there's a function defined for "When a process or job exits" or "When the prompt is about to be shown", based on: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#other . I don't know what they'd be named, though. Perhaps the output of `functions -n` or `functions -a` would hold a clue? Ahh - perhaps "fish_postexec"; fish_prompt was the other one.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - I've added the output of `functions -an` - I can't see an obvious one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm sure they are just some sort of mis-encoded control characters, but I'm just trying to work out what these two characters are,

`âŽ` is what happens when one displays the transmitted octets `\xc2` `\x8e` decoded with Windows code page 1252.  Your terminal emulator is using a single-byte character set.

Decoded as UTF-8, rather, that is the `SS2` control character.

So you have: something on the host end that thinks that it needs to send ISO 2022 control sequences to switch 7-bit character sets, even though (quite ironically) it's encoding those control sequences in UTF-8; and a terminal emulator that isn't speaking UTF-8.

There's more ISO 2022 in the prompt string that you hex-dumped.  `\x1b` `\x28` `\x42` is where your shell (apparently in its `set_color normal` command) sent the ISO 2022-JP sequence to switch to ASCII.

The simplest cure is this:  Make your terminal emulator speak UTF-8.  Stop your host programs thinking that they need to do any sort of ISO 2022 character set switching *at all* and tell them to just speak UTF-8 too.

You might want to check your terminal type, too.  Your terminal type (sent originally from your terminal emulation program to your host) *must* match the actual behaviour of your terminal emulation program.  Making "But it's `xterm`, right?" decisions, or just picking arbitrary terminal types, rarely works well.

The right terminal type for PuTTY is in fact something like [`putty`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty) or [`putty-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-256color) or [`putty-sco`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-sco) for example.